# To get directory path in reverse from file path

Tags: c, linux, recursion

Suppose I have a file name /A/B/C/d.txt,

I want to print the directory path in reverse,

```
/A/B/C/
/A/B/
/A/
```

Below is a program using recursion to print the directory path in reverse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void parsepath(const char *dirpath)
{
    char* dirPathTemp;  
    char* dirname;
    char path[255];  

    dirPathTemp = strdup(dirpath);
    dirname = dirname(dirPathTemp);     
    strcpy(path, dirname);

    free(dirPathTemp);  

    printf("path = %s\n", path);    

    if (0 != strcmp(path, "/"))
        parsepath(path);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    parsepath("/A/B/C/d.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any other way to do this without recursion? Thanks.

Comment: Aw, cmon.  A simple loop will do the trick - simply check individual characters rather then relying on string functions.  Simply work backward through the path.   Incidentally, `strdup()` may be okay for linux, but is not standard C.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

Following algorithm is simple: each time it searches input string for last occurence of `'/'`, replaces it with `'\0'` (end-of-string marker) and prints it, continuing until there are no more slashes in path. Copying input string is necessary, as it has to be modified in-place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void parsepath(const char *dirpath)
{
    char *p = strdup(dirpath);
    char *lastslash;
    while(lastslash = strrchr(p, '/')) {
        *lastslash = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", p);
    }
    free(p);
}

int main(void) {
    parsepath("/A/B/C/d.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* `strrchr()` searches input string from the beginning, which is not optimal. As each time last occurence of slash is wanted, searching backwards would be preferable. That's what `memrchr()` function does. Replacing `strrchr()` with `memrchr()` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This looks simple. Thanks for the notes on memchr.